Generator Wiring to HVAC Panel
My house is wired for a backup portable generator.  There is a an outdoor plug located next to a door leading out of my basement.  The plug is wired to a Ronk 200 amp mechanical transfer switch in my basement.  My electric company service wire is all underground, and comes from a large green metered electrical box in the front yard (which has a lever to switch to aux power).  As I understand it there is a 200 amp service wired from that main box to the Ronk transfer switch and then on to a 200 amp panel in the main floor of my home.
Here's my issue.  There is another 200 amp electric panel in the basement next to the Ronk switch that is also serviced directly by the main metered box.  This panel has my geothermal HVAC and well pump circuit breakers (the geo is a water-water system and needs well water).  I would like to be able to run my HVAC and well during power outages.
So my question is, is it possible to get generator power to this basement panel? I'm guessing that backfeeding is the only way, but I am well aware of the issues involved with doing that. Would it be a matter of connecting/bridging the main floor generator-fed electric panel to the basement HVAC panel?  Or can the Ronk transfer switch be backfed to the nearby HVAC panel, wired to a dedicated CB and a generator interlock kit installed to protect the grid.  I would certainly throw any non-essential CB's to keep the power requirements manageable.  Or, can this just not be done at all.
I will throw another curveball into this.  There is an additional meter at the main service box which is used to provide me a discount on my bill since they can restrict (water heater, HVAC) usage during high demand times.  That meter monitors the basement panel with a load controller.  So, if the solution to my problem would be to just move some CB's around and put the HVAC/well on the main floor generator-serviced panel that would not be an option.
If it can be done I know I will have to buy a bigger generator than the 7500 watt I currently have.  Of note, I do know there are bare terminals located inside the big green service box that are dedicated for a generator (I'm guessing to run whole house). I could have a generator plug installed there and place the portable generator in my garage, but it is a fairly long distance needing expensive heavy gauge wire.  If I would go with this option it obviously renders the Ronk transfer switch useless, making it one big junction box. Thanks.

Who is your electric utility?   This sounds like a pretty messy setup....
